# Rick Wright's style of playing

Tags: technique, composition, styles

Some of you might know Richard Wright from Pink Floyd. I've been studying his technique and his style for a few years now. Especially the way he builds up harmony. Unfortunately I couldn't find any material that explains his style or technique. There's so much about Gilmour but almost nothing about Rick, Roger or Nick.

**Could someone explain how he builds up harmony and uses sounds?**

It seems like people aren't that much interested in keyboard players.

I would also much appreciate if someone gave me a link to the list of gear he used in songs. Please!

Comment: I wonder if this question might be clearer if it were narrowed a bit. I'm not familiar with the concept of how one builds harmony. Do you mean, how does he choose which notes to play? If you are actually asking about what gear he uses, that should be a separate question but I would doibke check the help center carefully because it might be off topic.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I mean how does he know what chord fits to what David is playing. Does he overlap the bass notes or add up to them in harmony. Does he intentionally play notes that aren't in the arpeggio or the chords that David plays. What are the scales he plays in and etc.

Comment: Nick Mason's technique can be summarised as: _play some simple patterns in an uninteresting way that won't distract from what your colleagues are doing_...

Answer (score 3):

One of your comments mentions that you wonder how Rick found chords that fit well with David's playing, but I do not think that's how it goes. The songwriter (whether it be Rick, Roger, David, Syd, or a combination of all of them) came up with a certain chord sequence, and Rick applied his own input to this to adapt it into what he wanted it to be. The melodies and harmonizations were then based on the chords that Rick and David played -- not the other way around.

To properly answer your question: I think you're best off simply researching jazz music theory. Rick Wright was a rock musician, but his style was distinctive because he applied a lot of jazzy influences, using chords you don't normally hear in rock music.

Comment: I read a lot about rock, blues and jazz piano. I can't understand some moments of Rick's style. I wonder if someone studied his style and scales.